# How to display different fields in different section using fieldsets

Tags: visualforce, opportunity, fieldsets

I have this below code where i trying to display fields present in fieldsets in vf page. The problem which i am facing is , Suppose i have 10 fields f1, f2....., f10 in fieldsset "FS1" , i need to display 5 fields under one section and 5 fields under another section.

How can i do it?

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity">
    <apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock >
     <apex:pageBlockButtons >
     <apex:commandButton value="Share" action="{!URLFOR($Action.Opportunity.Share, Opportunity.id)}"/>
     </apex:pageBlockButtons>
     <apex:pageBlockSection title="Opportunity Detail" collapsible="true">
     <apex:repeat value="{!$ObjectType.Opportunity.FieldSets.Test_Fields}" 
                        var="field">
                  <apex:outputField value="{!Opportunity[field]}" />
               </apex:repeat>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>

    <apex:pageBlockSection title="Admin Only" collapsible="true">

    </apex:pageBlockSection>

               </apex:pageBlock>
     </apex:form> 
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use two `Fieldsets`.

```
<apex:pageBlockSection ...>
    <apex:repeat var="field" value="{!$ObjectType.Opportunity.FieldSets.Test_Fields1}">
    </apex:repeat>
</apex:pageBlockSection>
<apex:pageBlockSection ...>
    <apex:repeat var="field" value="{!$ObjectType.Opportunity.FieldSets.Test_Fields2}">
    </apex:repeat>
</apex:pageBlockSection>
```

The ordering should be like:

```
Field 1 | Field 2
Field 3 | Field 4
```

Field set:

```
Field 1
Field 2
Field 3
Field 4
```

Comment: ok after doing this can we reorder the fields accordingly..like i want fields f1 & f3 to be side by side..

Comment: @user2542953 Then the field set order should be f1, f3, f2, f4. If you want blanks you may need to add an empty custom text field and reference that.

Comment: Yes you would also need to tweak it to hide the label if you add blanks.